# White border when using IDCompositionGaussianBlurEffect

Tags: c++, winapi, window, directx, direct-composition

My main goal is to create Acrylic effect like in Windows UWP Settings UI in C++ for windows. For creating back visual I'm using private API DwmpCreateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual, this works. But now when I apply the gaussian effect using IDCompositionGaussianBlurEffect to the rootvisual that produces white borders like in the following image, I tried several things like scaling the root visual and translating to hide the borders but it's not working.

[image]

```cpp
#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <d2d1_2.h>
#include <d2d1_2helper.h>
#include <d3d11_2.h>
#include <dcomp.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <dxgi1_3.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <wrl\implements.h>

void WINAPIV debug(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    char s[2048];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(s, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    OutputDebugStringA(s);
}

//Either use this or add in your linker configuration
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")
#pragma comment(lib, "dcomp")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi")
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32")

//-------------------- Definitions
enum THUMBNAIL_TYPE {
    TT_DEFAULT = 0x0,
    TT_SNAPSHOT = 0x1,
    TT_ICONIC = 0x2,
    TT_BITMAPPENDING = 0x3,
    TT_BITMAP = 0x4
};

typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DwmpCreateSharedThumbnailVisual)(
    IN HWND hwndDestination,
    IN HWND hwndSource,
    IN DWORD dwThumbnailFlags,
    IN DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES* pThumbnailProperties,
    IN VOID* pDCompDevice,
    OUT VOID** ppVisual,
    OUT PHTHUMBNAIL phThumbnailId);

typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DwmpQueryWindowThumbnailSourceSize)(
    IN HWND hwndSource,
    IN BOOL fSourceClientAreaOnly,
    OUT SIZE* pSize);

typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DwmpQueryThumbnailType)(
    IN HTHUMBNAIL hThumbnailId,
    OUT THUMBNAIL_TYPE* thumbType);

//pre-cobalt/pre-iron
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DwmpCreateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual)(
    IN HWND hwndDestination,
    IN VOID* pDCompDevice,
    OUT VOID** ppVisual,
    OUT PHTHUMBNAIL phThumbnailId);

//cobalt/iron (20xxx+)
//No changes except for the function name.
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DwmpCreateSharedMultiWindowVisual)(
    IN HWND hwndDestination,
    IN VOID* pDCompDevice,
    OUT VOID** ppVisual,
    OUT PHTHUMBNAIL phThumbnailId);

//pre-cobalt/pre-iron
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DwmpUpdateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual)(
    IN HTHUMBNAIL hThumbnailId,
    IN HWND* phwndsInclude,
    IN DWORD chwndsInclude,
    IN HWND* phwndsExclude,
    IN DWORD chwndsExclude,
    OUT RECT* prcSource,
    OUT SIZE* pDestinationSize);

//cobalt/iron (20xxx+)
//Change: function name + new DWORD parameter.
//Pass "1" in dwFlags. Feel free to explore other flags.
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DwmpUpdateSharedMultiWindowVisual)(
    IN HTHUMBNAIL hThumbnailId,
    IN HWND* phwndsInclude,
    IN DWORD chwndsInclude,
    IN HWND* phwndsExclude,
    IN DWORD chwndsExclude,
    OUT RECT* prcSource,
    OUT SIZE* pDestinationSize,
    IN DWORD dwFlags);

#define DWM_TNP_FREEZE 0x100000
#define DWM_TNP_ENABLE3D 0x4000000
#define DWM_TNP_DISABLE3D 0x8000000
#define DWM_TNP_FORCECVI 0x40000000
#define DWM_TNP_DISABLEFORCECVI 0x80000000

//We also need these if you want to use MultiWindow/VirtualDesktop.

enum WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIB {
    WCA_UNDEFINED = 0x0,
    WCA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED = 0x1,
    WCA_NCRENDERING_POLICY = 0x2,
    WCA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED = 0x3,
    WCA_ALLOW_NCPAINT = 0x4,
    WCA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS = 0x5,
    WCA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT = 0x6,
    WCA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION = 0x7,
    WCA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS = 0x8,
    WCA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP = 0x9,
    WCA_THEME_ATTRIBUTES = 0xA,
    WCA_NCRENDERING_EXILED = 0xB,
    WCA_NCADORNMENTINFO = 0xC,
    WCA_EXCLUDED_FROM_LIVEPREVIEW = 0xD,
    WCA_VIDEO_OVERLAY_ACTIVE = 0xE,
    WCA_FORCE_ACTIVEWINDOW_APPEARANCE = 0xF,
    WCA_DISALLOW_PEEK = 0x10,
    WCA_CLOAK = 0x11,
    WCA_CLOAKED = 0x12,
    WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 0x13,
    WCA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION = 0x14,
    WCA_EVER_UNCLOAKED = 0x15,
    WCA_VISUAL_OWNER = 0x16,
    WCA_HOLOGRAPHIC = 0x17,
    WCA_EXCLUDED_FROM_DDA = 0x18,
    WCA_PASSIVEUPDATEMODE = 0x19,
    WCA_LAST = 0x1A,
};

typedef struct WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA {
    WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIB Attrib;
    void* pvData;
    DWORD cbData;
};

typedef BOOL(WINAPI* SetWindowCompositionAttribute)(
    IN HWND hwnd,
    IN WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA* pwcad);

typedef BOOL(WINAPI* GetWindowCompositionAttribute)(
    IN HWND hwnd,
    OUT WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA* pAttrData
    );

//------------------------- Getting functions
DwmpQueryThumbnailType lDwmpQueryThumbnailType;
DwmpCreateSharedThumbnailVisual lDwmpCreateSharedThumbnailVisual;
DwmpQueryWindowThumbnailSourceSize lDwmpQueryWindowThumbnailSourceSize;

//PRE-IRON
DwmpCreateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual lDwmpCreateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual;
DwmpUpdateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual lDwmpUpdateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual;

//20xxx+
DwmpCreateSharedMultiWindowVisual lDwmpCreateSharedMultiWindowVisual;
DwmpUpdateSharedMultiWindowVisual lDwmpUpdateSharedMultiWindowVisual;

SetWindowCompositionAttribute lSetWindowCompositionAttribute;
GetWindowCompositionAttribute lGetWindowCompositionAttribute;

bool InitPrivateDwmAPIs()
{
    auto dwmapiLib = LoadLibrary(L"dwmapi.dll");

    if (!dwmapiLib)
        return false;

    lDwmpQueryThumbnailType = (DwmpQueryThumbnailType)GetProcAddress(dwmapiLib, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(114));
    lDwmpCreateSharedThumbnailVisual = (DwmpCreateSharedThumbnailVisual)GetProcAddress(dwmapiLib, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(147));
    lDwmpQueryWindowThumbnailSourceSize = (DwmpQueryWindowThumbnailSourceSize)GetProcAddress(dwmapiLib, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(162));

    //PRE-IRON
    lDwmpCreateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual = (DwmpCreateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual)GetProcAddress(dwmapiLib, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(163));
    lDwmpUpdateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual = (DwmpUpdateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual)GetProcAddress(dwmapiLib, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(164));

    //20xxx+
    lDwmpCreateSharedMultiWindowVisual = (DwmpCreateSharedMultiWindowVisual)GetProcAddress(dwmapiLib, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(163));
    lDwmpUpdateSharedMultiWindowVisual = (DwmpUpdateSharedMultiWindowVisual)GetProcAddress(dwmapiLib, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(164));

    if (false) //Just a placeholder, don't.
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool InitPrivateUser32APIs()
{
    auto user32Lib = LoadLibrary(L"user32.dll");

    if (!user32Lib)
        return false;

    lSetWindowCompositionAttribute = (SetWindowCompositionAttribute)GetProcAddress(user32Lib, "SetWindowCompositionAttribute");

    if (!lSetWindowCompositionAttribute)
        return false;

    lGetWindowCompositionAttribute = (GetWindowCompositionAttribute)GetProcAddress(user32Lib, "GetWindowCompositionAttribute");
    assert(lGetWindowCompositionAttribute);

    return true;
}

//--------------------- Create Device func
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

ComPtr<ID3D11Device> direct3dDevice;
ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice;
ComPtr<ID2D1Factory> d2dFactory2;
ComPtr<IDCompositionDesktopDevice> dcompDevice;
ComPtr<IDCompositionDevice3> dcompDevice3;

#include <vector>
std::vector<HWND> windowList;
ComPtr<IDCompositionVisual2> rootVisual;
ComPtr<IDCompositionRectangleClip> rootClip;
std::vector<ComPtr<IDCompositionVisual>> visuals;
ComPtr<IDCompositionTranslateTransform> translateTransform;
ComPtr<IDCompositionGaussianBlurEffect> gaussianEffect;
HWND gHWND{};
RECT gHWNDRect{};

bool CreateDevice()
{
    if (D3D11CreateDevice(0, //Adapter
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
        NULL,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        direct3dDevice.GetAddressOf(),
        nullptr,
        nullptr)
        != S_OK) {
        //Maybe try creating with D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP before returning false.
        //Always listen to device changes.
        return false;
    }

    if (direct3dDevice->QueryInterface(dxgiDevice.GetAddressOf()) != S_OK) {
        return false;
    }

    if (D2D1CreateFactory(
            D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE::D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
            __uuidof(ID2D1Factory2),
            (void**)d2dFactory2.GetAddressOf())
        != S_OK) {
        return false;
    }

    if (DCompositionCreateDevice3(
        dxgiDevice.Get(),
        __uuidof(dcompDevice),
        (void**)dcompDevice.GetAddressOf())
        != S_OK) {
        return false;
    }

    if (dcompDevice->QueryInterface(dcompDevice3.GetAddressOf()) != S_OK)
        return false;

    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
HWND CreateWindowInternal(LPCWSTR lptitleName, LPCWSTR lpclassName, DWORD dwExStyle, DWORD dwStyle)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MyWndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = lpclassName;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return nullptr;

    const auto hwndParent = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, lpclassName, lptitleName,
        dwStyle, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1000, 640,
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, NULL);


    if (!hwndParent)
        return nullptr;

    return hwndParent;
}

void DemoCreateWindowThumbnail(HWND targetWindow, HWND myWnd, IDCompositionVisual** ppWindowVisual)
{
    assert(targetWindow != myWnd);

    //Query the exact thumbnail source size
    SIZE windowSize{};
    lDwmpQueryWindowThumbnailSourceSize(targetWindow, FALSE, &windowSize);
    debug("windosize: %d %d\n", windowSize.cx, windowSize.cy);

    //Pretty explanatory and also documented by Microsoft
    DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES thumb{};
    thumb.dwFlags = DWM_TNP_SOURCECLIENTAREAONLY | DWM_TNP_VISIBLE | DWM_TNP_RECTDESTINATION | DWM_TNP_RECTSOURCE | DWM_TNP_OPACITY | DWM_TNP_ENABLE3D;
    thumb.opacity = 255;
    thumb.fVisible = TRUE;
    thumb.fSourceClientAreaOnly = FALSE;
    thumb.rcDestination = RECT{ 0, 0, windowSize.cx, windowSize.cy };
    thumb.rcSource = RECT{ 0, 0, windowSize.cx, windowSize.cy };

    HTHUMBNAIL hThumbWindow;
    //Create the shared visual!
    auto res = lDwmpCreateSharedThumbnailVisual(myWnd, targetWindow, 2, &thumb,
        dcompDevice.Get(), (void**)ppWindowVisual, &hThumbWindow);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(res)) {
        debug("failed create shared thumnail %d", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    RECT targetRect;
    GetWindowRect(targetWindow, &targetRect);
    (*ppWindowVisual)->SetOffsetX(targetRect.left);
    (*ppWindowVisual)->SetOffsetY(targetRect.top);

}

void DemoCreateMultiWindowThumbnail(HWND myWnd, IDCompositionVisual2** ppVirtualDesktopVisual)
{
    HTHUMBNAIL hThumbVirtualDesktop;
    auto virtualDeskRes = lDwmpCreateSharedMultiWindowVisual(myWnd, dcompDevice.Get(),
        (void**)ppVirtualDesktopVisual, &hThumbVirtualDesktop);

    auto monitorSize = RECT{ 0, 0, 1920, 1080 };
    auto targetSize = SIZE{ 960, 540 };

    HWND hwndTest = (HWND)0x1; //Exclude from the list what you want to exclude
    HWND* excludeArray = new HWND[1];
    excludeArray[0] = hwndTest;

    //The include list is useless as it will include every window in every case.
    //You can only play with the exclusion list.
    auto virtualDesktopUpdate = lDwmpUpdateSharedMultiWindowVisual(hThumbVirtualDesktop, NULL, 0,
        excludeArray, 1, &monitorSize, &targetSize, 1); //Last parameter has to be "1"

    //use lDwmpUpdateSharedVirtualDesktopVisual for 19043 or older
}


BOOL iswindowintersect(HWND hwnd)
{
    RECT hwndRect;
    if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, &hwndRect))
        return FALSE;

    RECT intersectRect;
    return IntersectRect(&intersectRect, &gHWNDRect, &hwndRect);
}

BOOL checkWindowVisible(HWND hwnd)
{
    BOOL attr = FALSE;
    WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA data{ WCA_CLOAKED, &attr, sizeof attr };
    if (!SUCCEEDED(lGetWindowCompositionAttribute(hwnd, &data)))
        debug("getwinattrr failed");
    return attr == 0 && IsWindowVisible(hwnd);
}

BOOL collectHWNDBehind(
    HWND hwnd,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (hwnd != gHWND && checkWindowVisible(hwnd) /*&& iswindowintersect(hwnd)*/)
        windowList.push_back(hwnd);

    return TRUE;
}

void buildVisual(BOOL recollectHWND)
{
    debug("building visual");
    if (!rootVisual)
    {
        debug("rootVisual is null");
        return;
    }

    GetWindowRect(gHWND, &gHWNDRect);

    if (recollectHWND)
    {
        windowList.clear();
        EnumWindows(collectHWNDBehind, NULL);
        debug("windowlist %zu\n", windowList.size());
    }


    rootVisual->RemoveAllVisuals();
    visuals.clear();
    for (auto window : windowList) {
        visuals.push_back({});
        auto& newVisual = visuals.back();
        DemoCreateWindowThumbnail(window, gHWND, newVisual.GetAddressOf());
        auto r = rootVisual->AddVisual(newVisual.Get(), TRUE, NULL);
        if (!SUCCEEDED(r))
        {
            debug("failed to add visual");
        }
    }

    dcompDevice->Commit();
    DwmFlush();
}

//------------------------ Create window func
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        buildVisual(TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED: {

        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
        rootClip->SetLeft((float)rect.left);
        rootClip->SetRight((float)rect.right);
        rootClip->SetTop((float)rect.top);
        rootClip->SetBottom((float)rect.bottom);
        rootVisual->SetClip(rootClip.Get());

        translateTransform->SetOffsetX(-1 * (float)rect.left - (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXPADDEDBORDER)));
        translateTransform->SetOffsetY(-1 * (float)rect.top - (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXPADDEDBORDER)));
        rootVisual->SetTransform(translateTransform.Get());

        gaussianEffect->SetBorderMode(D2D1_BORDER_MODE_HARD);
        gaussianEffect->SetStandardDeviation(20);
        rootVisual->SetEffect(gaussianEffect.Get());

        dcompDevice->Commit();
        DwmFlush();
        //buildVisual(FALSE);
        break;
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    if (!InitPrivateDwmAPIs() || !InitPrivateUser32APIs() || !CreateDevice())
        return 0;

    ComPtr<IDCompositionTarget> dcompTarget;

    dcompDevice->CreateVisual(rootVisual.GetAddressOf());
    if (!rootVisual) {
        debug("failed to initialize root visual");
        return 0;
    }

    dcompDevice->CreateRectangleClip(rootClip.GetAddressOf());
    if (!rootClip) {
        debug("failed to initialize root clip");
        return 0;
    }

    dcompDevice->CreateTranslateTransform(translateTransform.GetAddressOf());
    if (!translateTransform) {
        debug("failed to initialize translate transform");
        return 0;
    }
    dcompDevice3->CreateGaussianBlurEffect(gaussianEffect.GetAddressOf());
    if (!gaussianEffect)
    {
        debug("failed to initialise gaussian effect");
        return 0;
    }

    auto myWnd = CreateWindowInternal(L"Noice window", L"DwmThumbExampleClass", WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW /*| WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP*/, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
    ShowWindow(myWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
    gHWND = myWnd;

    //Create the target for the window.
    if (dcompDevice->CreateTargetForHwnd(myWnd, FALSE, dcompTarget.GetAddressOf()) != S_OK)
        return 0;

    //You can either set the virtual desktop visual as root or create a new visual and set the content.
    if (dcompTarget->SetRoot(rootVisual.Get()) != S_OK)
        return 0;

    //Remember to commit.
    if (dcompDevice->Commit() != S_OK)
        return 0;
    buildVisual(TRUE);
    MSG msg{};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //ComPtr automatically releases for you.
}
```

Comment: This is how gaussian blur works. A blurred pixel is the result of a span of pixels underneath. So if your resulting image is over a white background, the resulting image border pixels will be "whited". This is not how you can built the real acrylic brush. You must use Windows.UI.Composition ("WUC"), not Direct Composition. WUC is the (WinRT) evolution of DC that supports 1) building effects graph 2) the host back drop brush https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor.createhostbackdropbrush.

Comment: The acrylic recipe is here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/Materials/Acrylic/AcrylicBrush.cpp#L697 and here is a seminal example that demonstrates WinRT's WUC with standard Win32 desktop app: https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/62923cdacaba28fedc4f3dab6e0c12ec and another (C# Winforms) sample https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WinForms/AcrylicEffect

Comment: I've to compile with MinGW, these headers are not available there :(, the white borders seem to happen because maximized CSD windows add margins around them.

Comment: White borders happen because you have a white background. This is by design. As for mingw, good luck with that ... thing.