# can we apply shader on transparent window

Tags: c#, c++, shader, directx, hlsl

I am looking to apply a particular shader to a transparent window. for example, on a live desktop, I want to create a transparent window with some filters. something like the following (I have shader file for below filter)[image]

suggested by @SimonMourier using WinRT's Windows.Graphics.Capture to capture screen but not able to apply shader on the duplicated window. here is code I am trying:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "SimpleCapture.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <sal.h>
#include <new>
#include <warning.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include "PixelShader.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::System;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::Capture;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;

using namespace DirectX;

typedef struct _VERTEX
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 TexCoord;
} VERTEX;

//
// A vertex with a position and texture coordinate
//
SimpleCapture::SimpleCapture(
    IDirect3DDevice const& device,
    GraphicsCaptureItem const& item)
{
    m_item = item;
    m_device = device;

    // Set up 
    m_d3ddevice = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device);
    m_d3ddevice->GetImmediateContext(m_d3dContext.put());
    auto size = m_item.Size();

    m_swapChain = CreateDXGISwapChain(
        m_d3ddevice,
        static_cast<uint32_t>(size.Width),
        static_cast<uint32_t>(size.Height),
        static_cast<DXGI_FORMAT>(DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized),
        2);

    UINT Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_VS1);

    m_d3ddevice->CreateVertexShader(g_VS1, Size, nullptr, &m_VertexShader);

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC Layout[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };

    UINT NumElements = ARRAYSIZE(Layout);

    m_d3ddevice->CreateInputLayout(Layout, NumElements, g_VS1, Size, &m_InputLayout);

    m_d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(m_InputLayout);
    Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_main);


    // ADDED THIS
    Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_main);
    HRESULT hr = m_d3ddevice->CreatePixelShader(g_main, Size, nullptr, &m_PixelShader);


    // END OF ADDED CHANGES

    // Create framepool, define pixel format (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM), and frame size. 
    m_framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool::Create(
        m_device,
        DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
        2,
        size);
    m_session = m_framePool.CreateCaptureSession(m_item);
    m_frameArrived = m_framePool.FrameArrived(auto_revoke, { this, &SimpleCapture::OnFrameArrived });
}
// Start sending capture frames
void SimpleCapture::StartCapture()
{
    CheckClosed();
    m_session.StartCapture();
}

ICompositionSurface SimpleCapture::CreateSurface(
    Compositor const& compositor)
{
    CheckClosed();
    return CreateCompositionSurfaceForSwapChain(compositor, m_swapChain.get());
}

// Process captured frames
void SimpleCapture::Close()
{
    auto expected = false;
    if (m_closed.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true))
    {
        m_frameArrived.revoke();
        m_framePool.Close();
        m_session.Close();

        m_swapChain = nullptr;
        m_framePool = nullptr;
        m_session = nullptr;
        m_item = nullptr;
    }
}

void SimpleCapture::OnFrameArrived(
    Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& sender,
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
{
    auto newSize = false;

    {
        auto frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame();
        auto frameContentSize = frame.ContentSize();

        //if (frameContentSize.Width != m_lastSize.Width ||
        //    frameContentSize.Height != m_lastSize.Height)
        //{
        //    // The thing we have been capturing has changed size.
        //    // We need to resize our swap chain first, then blit the pixels.
        //    // After we do that, retire the frame and then recreate our frame pool.
        //    newSize = true;
        //    m_lastSize = frameContentSize;
        //    m_swapChain->ResizeBuffers(
        //        2,
        //        static_cast<uint32_t>(m_lastSize.Width),
        //        static_cast<uint32_t>(m_lastSize.Height),
        //        static_cast<DXGI_FORMAT>(DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized),
        //        0);
        //}

        /*auto d3dDevice = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device);
        d3dDevice->GetImmediateContext(m_d3dContext.put());*/

        {
            auto frameSurface = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Texture2D>(frame.Surface());

            com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
            check_hresult(m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), backBuffer.put_void()));

            m_d3ddevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer.get(), NULL, &m_RTV);

            // ADDED THIS
            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC txtDesc = {};
            txtDesc.MipLevels = txtDesc.ArraySize = 1;
            txtDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
            txtDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
            txtDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
            txtDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

            //auto d3dDevice = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device);

            ID3D11Texture2D* tex;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateTexture2D(&txtDesc, NULL,
                &tex);
            frameSurface.copy_to(&tex);

            ID3D11ShaderResourceView* srv_1;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateShaderResourceView(
                tex,
                nullptr,
                &srv_1
            );

            auto texture = srv_1;
            m_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);
            // END OF ADDED CHANGES

            // Create the sample state
            D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC SampDesc;
            RtlZeroMemory(&SampDesc, sizeof(SampDesc));
            SampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
            SampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
            SampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
            SampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
            SampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
            SampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
            SampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateSamplerState(&SampDesc, &m_SamplerLinear);

            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC FrameDesc;
            tex->GetDesc(&FrameDesc);

            D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC ShaderDesc;
            ShaderDesc.Format = FrameDesc.Format;
            ShaderDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
            ShaderDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = FrameDesc.MipLevels - 1;
            ShaderDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = FrameDesc.MipLevels;
            // Vertices for drawing whole texture
            VERTEX Vertices[NUMVERTICES] =
            {
                {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f)},
            };
            // Create new shader resource view
            ID3D11ShaderResourceView* ShaderResource = nullptr;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &ShaderDesc, &ShaderResource);
            // Set resources
            UINT Stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
            UINT Offset = 0;
            m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RTV, nullptr);
            m_d3dContext->VSSetShader(m_VertexShader, nullptr, 0);
            m_d3dContext->PSSetShader(m_PixelShader, nullptr, 0);
            m_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &ShaderResource);
            m_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_SamplerLinear);
            m_d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
            D3D11_BUFFER_DESC BufferDesc;
            RtlZeroMemory(&BufferDesc, sizeof(BufferDesc));
            BufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
            BufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * NUMVERTICES;
            BufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
            BufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
            D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
            RtlZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
            InitData.pSysMem = Vertices;

            ID3D11Buffer* VertexBuffer = nullptr;

            // Create vertex buffer
            m_d3ddevice->CreateBuffer(&BufferDesc, &InitData, &VertexBuffer);


            m_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &VertexBuffer, &Stride, &Offset);
            // Draw textured quad onto render target
            //m_d3dContext->CopyResource(backBuffer.get(), tex);
            m_d3dContext->Draw(NUMVERTICES, 0);
            // 
            //m_d3dContext->CopyResource(backBuffer.get(), frameSurface.get());
            //m_d3dContext->DrawAuto();
        }
    }

    DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS presentParameters = { 0 };
    m_swapChain->Present1(1, 0, &presentParameters);
}
```

more references are on:

- [Applying HLSL Pixel Shaders to Win32 Screen Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61515500/applying-hlsl-pixel-shaders-to-win32-screen-capture)
- [Screen capture for HWND](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/master/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND/README.md)

Comment: You can capture the desktop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api and run a pixel shader over the captured GPU surface/bitmap, or on Windows 10+ you can use WUC host backdrop brush, see my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987475/white-border-when-using-idcompositiongaussianblureffect#comment121929874_68987475

Comment: @SimonMourier! thanks for the comment. i did gabe try on desktop duplication but it's considering complete desktop instead of the specific reason or exe. can desktop duplication API allow to duplicate only specific reason or exercise?

Comment: WinRT's Windows.Graphics.Capture namespace implements DXGI duplication but it can capture from HWND too.

Comment: @SimonMourier can we apply shader on Windows.Graphics.Capture? tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61515500/applying-hlsl-pixel-shaders-to-win32-screen-capture but not able to apply shader

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. Capture will get you GPU frames (eg: bitmaps/surface/resources). But if you want to do something like that with it, you must copy them in other GPU objects first. The rest is details, code, sample that you should provide.

Comment: @SimonMourier updated source code with changes I am doing on screen capture.

Comment: please check this question if you are looking for similar way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158110/apply-pixel-shader-with-winrts-windows-graphics-capture/69285404#69285404